# Building an Invite Function [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm new to ruby on rails and would kindly appreciate any advise & guidance on how to create an invite function with ruby on rails. Building from scratch or any suggestions using a GEM would be much appreciated.

1. i've created an events platform where users can create their events & follower event organisers
2. i would like to create an invite function where users can invite followers/friends to the event
3. the invite function allows users to only invite members within the platform not non-members

i have my schema displayed below.

```
i would be grateful on any given advise of how to build an invite function
```

Schema

```
  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "time"
    t.text     "city"
    t.decimal  "price",       precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id"
    t.integer  "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.date     "dob"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "role"
  end

  create_table "votes", force: true do |t|
    t.boolean  "vote",          default: false, null: false
    t.integer  "voteable_id",                   null: false
    t.string   "voteable_type",                 null: false
    t.integer  "voter_id"
    t.string   "voter_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end 

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [gem devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)

A really useful extenison to the Devise authentication gem is **devise_invitable**. It adds invitation functionality that can be used for building a referral system or just general email invitations to your web app. It adds support to **[devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)** for sending invitations by email

The way it is works is extremely simple. It just adds a `invite!` method to the model and you can pass in attributes just like calling `create`.

**E.g.**

```
User.invite!(email: "new_user@example.com", name: "John Doe")
```

This is great, and it automatically keeps track of which user sent the invitation if you pass that object in:

```
User.invite!({:email => "new_user@example.com"}, current_user)
# current_user will be set as invited_by
```

for **[more info](https://gorails.com/blog/how-to-create-invitations-from-any-model-with-devise-invitable)**

---

### [RailsCast #124 Beta Invitations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations)

You can watch this rails cast which explain very nicely of invitation sytem.

Hope this helps..